# drop columns with null threshold number

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

Have a dataset and want to do some cleaning with pyspark. Drop all columns with >75% null values. with python:

```
df = df.dropna(axis='columns', thresh = int(0.75 * len(df)))
```

how do i achieve this with pyspark

Answer (score 0):

Let's create a fictitious `DataFrame`. The aim is to have only a DataFrame with columns `B,C & D`.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import count, when
valuesCol = [(None,21,12,None,1),(8,None,3,1,None),(None,40,None,10,None),(None,2,None,6,None),(None,8,0,2,None)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(valuesCol,['A','B','C','D','E'])
df.show()
+----+----+----+----+----+ 
|   A|   B|   C|   D|   E| 
+----+----+----+----+----+ 
|null|  21|  12|null|   1| 
|   8|null|   3|   1|null| 
|null|  40|null|  10|null| 
|null|   2|null|   6|null| 
|null|   8|   0|   2|null| 
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Now, let's aggregate the DataFrame and `collect()` it. `Collect` is an `action` that return all the elements of the `DataFrame` as an array at the driver program.

```
aggregated_row = df.select([(count(when(col(c).isNull(), c))/df.count()).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).collect()
aggregated_row
    [Row(A=0.8, B=0.2, C=0.4, D=0.2, E=0.8)]
```

Converting the `Row()` object to `list` of `dictionary` -

```
aggregated_dict_list = [row.asDict() for row in aggregated_row]
aggregated_dict = aggregated_dict_list[0]  
    {'D': 0.2, 'A': 0.8, 'C': 0.4, 'E': 0.8, 'B': 0.2}
```

Finally, using `dictionary comprehensions` to find those columns where the `Null` values are more than 75 % of the total and then dropping those columns -

```
col_null_g_75p=list({i for i in aggregated_dict if aggregated_dict[i] > 0.75})
print(col_null_g_75p)
    ['A', 'E']
df = df.drop(*col_null_g_75p)
df.show()
+----+----+----+ 
|   B|   C|   D| 
+----+----+----+ 
|  21|  12|null| 
|null|   3|   1| 
|  40|null|  10| 
|   2|null|   6| 
|   8|   0|   2| 
+----+----+----+
```

Comment: this is great! thank you very much. however does this work efficiently on large datasets? +8M rows and a few hundred columns

Comment: I can’t see any reason as to why it should not work.